# Strange error when manually scrolling UITableViewController to top

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I am calling the following method to scroll UITableViewController to the top.

```
func scrollTableToTop() {

    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated: true)

}
```

I have tried several lines of code within this function, and all of them return the same error, which I can't understand.

Here is the error in full:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245
```

Similar errors listed this website seem to cause the app to crash before any cells are loaded. But my tableView is fully functional with the cells loaded. The error leaves the app fully functional but will not scroll to top.

More confusion arises from the fact that tapping the status bar successfully scrolls the UITableViewController to the top in the exact behavior that I desire, but the function I have created will not run.

**Edit:**

As requested, here is how my `scrollTableToTop()` method is being called. 
In a .swift file connected to my tabBarController:

```
class tabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
}

//Scroll to top when tab is pressed
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if homeIsCurrentlyVisible == true {
        println("Should scroll home-page to top")
        homeTableViewController().scrollTableToTop()        
    }

}
```

`homeIsCurrentlyVisible` is a universal variable set to `true` when `homeTableViewController` appears, and `false` when it disappears. `homeTableViewController` is the tableView that needs to be scrolled to the top.

**Edit 2:**

I've got some insight! I re-searched stackoverflow for this error even though the posts seemed unrelated to my issue.

An answer suggested replacing `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. 
Upon trying that, when I tap the tab bar to scrollTableToTop I crash with error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

I'm unsure what's causing the difference in errors.

Next, and probably more important to solving this, is I filled my code to the brim with `println()` to find out where the crash was happening.

Here were my results:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    println("cellForRowAtIndexPath 1")

    super.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    //let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

    println("cellForRowAtIndexPath 2") //This line DOES NOT PRINT

...insert more random code here...

return myCell 

}
```

The first line prints to the console, then the app crashes before the second line. I'm quite positive this is the line the app crashes. 
Also, if I go back to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, the second line also doesn't print, but the app doesn't crash.

Why is my scrollTableToTop function causing the app to crash here?

And why does tapping the status bar to scroll to top not cause the problem?

Comment: @matt Yes, this is the entire error, exactly the same every time. My view is set up with a tabBarController. I call `scrollTableToTop()` when the tab for my `tableViewController` is pressed while it is already selected. I have checked by printing to the console to make sure the function is actually running.

Comment: @matt `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` results in the exact same error but interestingly it also terminates the app.

Comment: While I don't know what exactly you mean by "stepping out to the main thread," I've used your freakishly genius `delay` function both after the tab is tapped before the `scrollTableToTop()` is called and within the `scrollTableToTop()` function itself. Same error.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first but explained myself poorly. It was unsuccessful.

Comment: I actually tried `delay(1) { scrollTableToTop() }` in combination with `scrollTableToTop{ delay(1) { ...insert code...} }` to no success, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: I have the `scrollViewDidScroll` function set up which runs a decent amount of code, and it's possible that scrolling to top is messing with it. Good catch, I'm gonna look into that now.